# How can I remove a folder that no longer exists from my Finder sidebar in Lion?

Tags: finder, macos

There is a folder in my favorites in the sidebar of the finder on my Mac. That folder no longer exists, but for some reason it started showing up again as soon as I upgraded to Lion

When I right-click to delete the folder, nothing happens. Normally, for most folders, I see a "Remove from Sidebar" option, but alas, I do not for this folder.

Does anyone know a way to edit this list from the terminal? Has anyone else experienced this problem and found a solution?

Comment: My version is Catalina 10.15.6, an USB device added to my "favorites", but it's has been ejected and disappear from my Finder sidebar. But, it still exist in my Chrome "save as" pop window's destination list. So upset about it!
How to remove it ???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was having the same issue and here's what just worked for me:

Hold command, then drag it off the Favorites bar.  The item will turn into a little "poof" white cloud and when you release, it'll go away! Finally!

Comment: HA! I'm still running 10.6.8, and had this issue. Great to find this answer. It worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do as described [here](http://www.tidbits.com/article/12320):

> To remove something from the Finder sidebar, hold Command as you drag
>   it out.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is click with 2 fingers on your trackpad or ctrl+click on the item and 'remove from sidebar'.

Comment: Lyken, in my message I very clearly wrote that nothing happens when I right-click for this particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the CMD+Option drag doesn't work (Pre 10.6.7 and all 10.5 for example), I suggest re-creating the same filename in it's same location (if you remember) then deleting the sidebar item, then re-deleting the folder... this was much easier to explain to a non-technical user than modifying the .plists

Later versions of 10.6 and all 10.7 allow the cmd-option drag, so that's the easiest if it works.