# How to remove duplicate and unclickable Dropbox folder shortcut in Finder sidebar?

Tags: dropbox

Here is a screenshot of my Finder sidebar with the non-functional duplicate Dropbox folder shortcut:

[image: Screenshot of Finder sidebar with non-functional duplicate Dropbox folder shortcut]

How can I remove this non-functional duplicate Dropbox folder shortcut from the sidebar?

I have tried uninstalling Dropbox and deleting the following directories:

```
/Library/DropboxHelperTool
~/Dropbox.dropbox.cache
```

My `/Library/Contextual Menu Items` is empty despite what is written in the [Dropbox uninstalling instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/help/41/en).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a broken folder reference, and it could be removed by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> and dragging the shortcut off the sidebar.

Reference: [How can I remove a folder that no longer exists from my Finder sidebar in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/how-can-i-remove-a-folder-that-no-longer-exists-from-my-finder-sidebar-in-lion)